# Implement chat functionality in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

Is there any way to implement chat functionality like Facebook in Sharepoint? Any such OOB functionality?

Comment: I think that this question is too general to answer. Also, you don't need to use three question marks.

Comment: Could you please help me now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SharePoint isn't suitable for a ful scale Facebook copy in my opinion (for lots of technical and cost reasons) but there are companies out there that have products that provide some Facebook like functionality on top of SharePoint. Have a look at [Sepulveda](http://www.bluerooster.com/Pages/Solutions.aspx) to start with.

Creating your own is going to be a heck of a lot of work and well out of scope for any kind of answer that could be provided in a Q&A site like this.

Comment: Please have look to the question now.